# Why would a post about helping people expand their career for FREE in a "Workplace" community be deleted?

Tags: discussion

I've just joined today, and tried to post what could be determined as self-promotion but there is no other way to explain or show what I have built or why I'm asking the question at the bottom - which I don't think is open ended or a survey - it was a genuine ask from a niche community.

Mine is just a free community aimed at helping people get a better job and expanding their knowledge by connecting with othe architects etc..... there is no Architecture community here that I'm aware of, otherwise I would have asked it in that sensibly..... can someone tell me (as that's also a question) why you'd delete a career benefitting post in a career forum? Or is something else this community?

PS I am not a spammer as suggested by someone, I've helped people for years get new jobs and earn more and have never asked for a penny from them (Sorry I'm Scottish so its pounds and pence).

I made this new post as I can't actually reply to the user who deleted it (what poor functionality), which is quite frustrating. I chose "Workplace" as a relevant "career" related community. Clearly it's full of non-career related people with 5 down votes in 2 minutes! Am I wrong on user type here? Enlighten me?

If it's an HR community asking questions about legal matters etc, then I won't waste my time offering help.

I'm happy to pay for ads, if thats how I would drive traffic for a "PAID" site.

If someone wants to chat to me in DM's about this then thats fine, I'm happy to be guided on the protocol. If they also want to just not help, thats also fine. Maybe everyone has a great job and doesn't want to earn more or have a more interesting job.

Comment: You will want the meta stack exchange. You could've found all this by checking the guidelines for here, which you didn't do.

Comment: This isn’t a place to promote your free community. The reason you cannot submit a comment is because you have to earn that privilege after you have proven you understand how to positively contribute to the community. If you don’t have a question that falls within the guidelines described in the help center, then whatever you submit, will be deleted by the community

Comment: It seems like you've misunderstood what this site is for - it would be good to take the [tour]. I'm sorry you were mistaken for a spammer when you believed you were posting something helpful. The community here gets a little testy when people jump in without lurking a little bit to see what the site is about, especially when it seems like it is just to advertise something.

Comment: We are not a forum. We don’t have discussions. We don’t promote other communities. We ask questions about issues within the workplace

Comment: Also, we don't do direct messages here.  The best you could do is enter the chat room, but you'll need 20 rep first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's obviously not intended as an actual question, but instead intended to continue to generate leads and interest (see the last paragraph especially). This is either a scam or a multi-level marketing scheme.

Comment: Maybe its not the site for me. Shame, I thought I could have added value for some, but maybe if its just a questions and answers site, not a discussion/discovery of info then I'll take my questions elsewhere.

Comment: I do love however how everyone wants to tell me off..... I'm 49, not 4! lol

Comment: Jack, I'm not a scammer...... I'm an Enterprise Architect. I work for banks, government and healhcare and I think if I was a scammer then I'd hardly have any work with them. Thank you to CollenV for kindly pointting me in the right direction and bveing so helpful.  If there isn't a community for my type of questions then mayeb thats the problem here.

Comment: @PaulIngram, There is a site called "**stack exchange software engineering**". Maybe, that site is somewhat related to your idea for the **Architect** forum. Please check it out.

Comment: Thank you Job_September_2020

Answer (score 7):

As others have told your post was closed because that's **not** what we do here - we're a Q&A site, we're not a forum, we're not a discussion site. And we're definitely not a place for you to promote your community, or your site or your services. Paid or not.

If you want to run ads here you can [contact](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/contact) Stack Exchange the company, and select "Other" and "I would like to advertise on Stack Exchange", I'm afraid I can't help you any more on that as I'm just a moderator, I don't work for SE.

I appreciate that if you're new to the Stack Exchange network that this can be confusing, and that is why I would highly recommend the [tour](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour) - it really is the best way to go from zero to understanding what this site is and how it works. If it's not for you, no worries - and I wish you all the best in your endeavours.

But if you want to join the community, *great*, but I would remind you that we expect users here to adhere to the [Code of Conduct](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/conduct) at all times.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably lurk as its not been a great experience so maybe need to observe for a bit. Appreciate the link and taking the time to explain things. Would have been nice if the majority of the others had done the same. I don't think the tour is well publicised so clearly didn't see it, but have taken it now as Collen was kind enough to share the link. If I want to do adverts then I'd be slightly unsure for now as its not the best bang for buck when your first post makes you want to leave. I also tried to upvote your comment....but obviosuly cant

Comment: Quick one - whats the discussion button mean? Serious question.....maybe thats not helping.....

Comment: @Paul Ingram It's a tag rather than a button (think of it as a form of category for your post here), and it's one that's unique to the "meta" sites such as this one where we post *about* the main site  - you may have noticed this post was "migrated" from the main site where we do Q&A about workplace issues to this one where it looks pretty similar but the colour scheme is different etc

Comment: More on what meta is and how it works [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: thanks or the link

Answer (score 2):

To add to the good answer by @motosubatsu - Many people who post regularly here are career professionals - Myself, I've worked in the IT industry for nearly 20 years.

Now to be clear I didn't see your original post or interact with it before it was deleted, but after looking through the deleted posts section, I can see immediately why it was nuked and why you got a negative response.

For the sake of comment - I'm going to assume the noblest of intentions on your part - you must understand that SE in general gets a lot of traffic and even though WP is tiny compared to say Stack Overflow or any of the other 'big' SE, we still get a pretty regular amount of Questions (about 3-4 per day). As such, anything that looks or smells like advertising/Bot/not our core functionality tends to get a swift and blunt response.

Your original question reads like Spam.

We exist to help people in their professional dealings. Questions on how to handle workplace situations, questions on professional etiquette etc.

Now, as a general rule, the closer someone is to what we can help with, the more lenient we are. For example - we have a 'No legal questions' policy - but invariably we get questions that touch on Law pretty regularly - a recent one being about Wage theft in Germany.

Sometimes we get questions where it's a situation we can empathize with, but we are unable to assist - a classic example being the 'Which option should we choose' type questions - but even with those, a particularly well-worded question may elicit answers where people give *a framework* on how to make the decision.

Your post on the other hand comes across as 'Use my product, make my product better, make me more prestigious' - that's a mile away from our mission and as such would have gotten a frosty reception.

Think of it like this - Imagine you went to a local builders and asked them to paint you the Mona Lisa, for free - how do you think that conversation would go down?

Comment: Cheers TDL for giving the benefit of the doubt. What I linked to is a FREE option, and yes I have paid mentoring classes but I pay for LinkedIn ads for that and was considering paid ads here for that, but what I was offering, but also asking for views on seems to not be a fit for what people suggest they use this site for, so I'll refrain from asking those types of questions as its suggested this is not a "forum" or discussion site just a Q&A (even though I think thats what I am after which is opinons which could be a simply "answer" to help people progress either their career or someone . ;)